# Check that length of several list is greater than some constant

Tags: python, list

I have stumble upon some issue with list. I have several lists I would to check if the length of each **list > 5** and **raise exception if this is true otherwise not**.

Please use this lists below as sample.

```
# Set up list of all inputs for function
t = [1, 3, 5, 8, 18, 34]
d = ['07/13/2020 07:48 AM', '05/17/2020 01:34 AM', '06/13/2020 05:25 AM',
         '03/26/2020 09:46 PM', '05/10/2020 12:11 PM', '03/25/2020 03:36 AM']
n = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1]
tr= [156, 89, 743, 425, 987, 209]
p = [45, 23, 88, 110, 150, 124]
```

In this case function should raise exception. In order not to raise exception each length of list should be 5 or less.
Would like to suggest some list comprehension way of solving this problem?

Comment: Can you please share what you have done and where do you have specific questions?

Comment: Try - `try` check each list len, `except`... Maybe.

Comment: So far I was able to do only this. To check that at least one of the list has different length. `length = len(t)
if all(len(lst) != length for lst in [d, n, tr, p]):
    # at least one list has a different length
    raise Exception("The list are not in correct lenght")
    `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function to check your lists:

```
def check_len(*args):
    for l in args:
        if len(l)>5:
            raise Exception('List {} has length>5'.format(l))

# to run
check_len(t, d, n, tr, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Exception` for this

```py
class CustomeException(Exception):
    pass

def check_length_of_list(l):
    assert isinstance(l, list), 'please provide list only'
    if(len(l) > 5):
        raise CustomeException('legth of list should be <= 5')

check_length_of_list(your_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of all lists

```
list_of_lists = [t, d, n ,tr, p]
for l in lists: 
  if len(l) > 5:
    raise Exception('A list ist longer than 5.')
```

or just check every list:

```
if len(t) < 5 and len(d) <5 ...:
  raise Exception('A list ist longer than 5.')
```

edit: list as variable name

Comment: Using `list` as the name of a variable is bad practice as it shadows the built-in `list`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [t,d,v,tr,p]
for i lst:
     if len(i)>5:
        raise Exception("{} has more than 5 items".format(i))
     else:
        print(i,"is fine")
```